# Infinite inequality with logarithm

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Solve inequality
$3 - \log_{0.5}x - \log^2_{0.5}x - \log^3_{0.5}x - \cdots \ge 4\log_{0.5}x$
Any suggestions how to start?

Comment: Let $u = \log_{0.5} x$. Find the admissible $u$.

Comment: Then we have $3 - u - u^2 - u^3 - ... \ge 4u$. Still, have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
3-\log_{0.5}x-\log^2_{0.5}x-\log^3_{0.5}x-\cdots&=4-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\log^n_{0.5}x\\\\
&=4-\frac{1}{1-\log_{0.5}x}\\\\
&=\frac{3-4\log_{0.5}x}{1-\log_{0.5}x}
\end{align}$$

for $|\log_{0.5}x|<1\implies 0.5<x<2$.  Now note that the inequality

$$\frac{3-4\log_{0.5}x}{1-\log_{0.5}x}\ge 4\log_{0.5}x$$

is equivalent to

$$\left(2\log_{0.5}x-3\right)\left(2\log_{0.5}x-1\right)\ge 0$$

which implies $\log_{0.5}x\le 0.5$ or $x\ge \sqrt{2}/2$.  Therefore, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sqrt{2}/2\le x<2}$$

Comment: Thank you. I forogt about formula for sum of infinite geometric series.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Please check to ensure that these inequalities make sense to you.

Comment: Yes, I understand them.

Comment: Excellent!  Pleased to hear.